# How can I use $_GET in the same page

Tags: php, list, get, action

My pseudo code is as follows:

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'list'){

do function getFileList($dir)

else

do nothing
 exit;
 }
require_once "./dir.php";
require_once "./echo.php";

function getFileList($dir)
  {
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your psuedo code is almost there.

```
require_once "./dir.php";
require_once "./echo.php";

function getFileList($dir)
{
   /* ... */   
}

if($_GET['action'] == 'list') {
   getFileList($dir);
}
```

Comment: i get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/se7encla/public_html/update.php on line 39 for if($_GET['action'] == 'list') {
   getFileList($dir)
}

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to send a variable via GET to a PHP file from within the same PHP file? You can create a form that submits to itself: http://www.tellingmachine.com/post/Simple-self-submitting-PHP-forms.aspx.

If you are looking to do something else, please provide additional details.